# What does "disingenuous“ really mean in English? Any good definitions?

Tags: meaning

It is like *hypocritical*? German translating dictionaries give me "unaufrichtig" mostly but I think that's only an approximation. I'm not sure I am really understanding the word.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts; for example, looking up *disingenuous* in a decent learner's dictionary like [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disingenuous) or [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/disingenuous), which will give the definition as *insincere* or *deceptively dishonest* rather than *hypocritical*. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *Merriam-Webster*:

> [Disingenuous Has a Roman History](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous)
>
> **Ingenous** has its roots in the slave-holding society of ancient Rome. Its ancestor ingenuus is a Latin adjective meaning "**native**" or "**freeborn**" (itself from gignere, meaning "to beget"). Ingenuus begot the English adjective ingenuous. That adjective originally meant "freeborn" (as in "ingenuous Roman subjects") or "noble and honorable," but it eventually came to mean "**showing childlike innocence**" or "lacking guile." In the mid-17th century, **English speakers combined the negative prefix dis- with ingenuous to create disingenuous, meaning "guileful" or "deceitful."**

So people flipped the term *ingenuous* which was used to describe people who were harmless or innocent like a child. They used the *dis* prefix to do so. So, we have *disingenuous*, which refers to someone who acts very much **not** like a child, someone who is cunning, crafting, and destructively self-interested. It's not a hypocrite, it's someone who is not honest and knows it and is trying to hide it. Someone "lacking in [candor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candor)".